# plural or singular verb after "which"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

There is a sentence lengthiness of which has made me suspicious about whether *which play* or *which plays* should be incorporated in the sentence.

> Special design of park’s designer has been so that in furniture design and selection of trees, different ages have been considered, *which plays* a significant role in understanding the park environment and citizens’ communication.

I mean that design of the park plays a significant role. That's why I used *plays* instead of *play* but is this correct given the fact that other words have come between first part (*design*) and the relative clause?

Answer (score 5):

> Special design of park’s designer has been so that in furniture design and selection of trees, different ages have been considered, **which plays** a significant role in understanding the park environment and citizens’ communication.

In this sentence in its current form, the [antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar)) of **which** is not the singular noun **design**. The relative pronoun **which** here is a stand-in for "*the **fact** that the designer of the park was influenced by diverse cultural epochs in his work*". That's why the singular **plays** is okay.

As to the sentence on the whole, it is formed in such a way that I don't understand it fully, especially the part about "citizen communication".